# irregularities with the setMaximumFractionDigits

Tags: java

In the code below, I am wondering why an exception will be thrown :

```
import java.text.*;
 class NumFormat
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
      String s = "123.456xyz";
      NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
      System.out.println(nf.parse(s));
      nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
     System.out.println(nf.format(s));
    }
 }
```

Comment: `NumberFormat.format()` doesn't accept `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format()` expects a number to format, where as `parse()` returns a number from a string.

```
double n = nf.parse(s);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(nf.format(n));
```

Will give you the result you were expecting.

#### References:

[format() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double))

[parse() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to test this instead. You can't pass a string to the format() method, it wants a number.

```
try {
    String s = "123.456xyz";
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    Number n = nf.parse(s);
    System.out.println(n);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    System.out.println(nf.format(n));

}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

An exception will be thrown if the number formatter fails to parse the input. Like if you change the first line to something like:

```
String s = "%123.456xyz";
```